# Make a table from imported list in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I get output from a program imported to Excel in the following format:

```
Item 1  
1       10
2       10
3       20
5       20
8       30
13      30
Item 2  
1       40
2       40
3       50
5       50
8       60
13      60
Item 3  
1       50
2       50
3       40
5       40
8       30
13      30
```

Now, I want to create a table where the values for each item is placed next to each other as below:

```
        Item 1      Item 2      Item 3
1       10          40          50
2       10          40          50
3       20          50          40
5       20          50          40
8       30          60          30
13      30          60          30
```

I can think of ways to do this using formulas with a combination of `INDIRECT` other functions, but I can see right away that it will be a huge pain. Is there a clever way of doing this?

My approach would be something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP($A6;indirect("A"&(6+G$5*$X$4):"D"&(30+G$5*$X$4));4;FALSE)
```

where my first lookup table is from `A6:D30`, the second from `A32:D56`. `X4` contains the value `26` which is the number of rows for each Item, and `G5:AA5` is `0, 1, 2 ...`. 
I would place this besides the `Item 1` list and drag it sideways and downwards. I think the procedure should work, but I get syntax error.

I don't have much experience writing VBA, but I'm capable of reading and understanding it.

**UPDATE:**

At Siddharth's request:

[image]

Comment: is `1` in column A and `10` in column `B`? Is column `B` always empty when there is a header row (ie. `Item 1`)? Is the number of *numbers* in between items always constant?

Comment: I would do something along the line of adding two columns to table a and populating the with VLOOKUP function to each of the other two tables.

Comment: `I don't have much experience writing VBA, but I'm capable of reading and understanding it.` Perfect opportunity to try it then ;) And when you do it, post the code that you tried and the error that you are getting and we can then take it form there?

Comment: @mehow: When there is a heading (always in A), all other columns are empty. The elements I want is actually in column D, (column B and C are not of interest). I didn't include that info in the question to make it as simple as possible, I can probably adapt it myself.

Comment: @RobertP. are `1 to 13` always constant? I mean is there always going to be the same number of items?

Comment: @mehow: Yes, they are the same for all items.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Thanks for your comments. I'm afraid I don't know where to start on this... I have included one of my (non-VBA) attempts in the question text (the one I think should be closest to solving the problem). Do you see where and why it fails?

Comment: Are you looking for a VBA or Formula option? I would recommend Formulas for this though...

Comment: @SiddharthRout: If formulas are best, then I'm looking for formulas =) Am I on the right track?

Comment: i am sure @mehow is already working on this at the moment but I will still take my chances :P Can you post a screenshot of how your worksheet looks like? So that I can test the formula before posting? (in case mehow doesn't post first)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Done =) It has some thousand rows

Comment: Wow if you have 1000's of rows then VBA is the best option. I was assuming that you have very less data and you could create an output table and put the formulas there...

Comment: Ok before I give you the code/formula, two questions. Will the data always start from row 5? And will the numbers 1 to 49 will be the same for all items?

Comment: The first heading is at row 5, yes! Thanks again! I might have been too quick there, the number of Items I get is varying. Sometimes there are only 100-300 rows, and sometimes around 2000. But most often less than 1000. Sorry about the mix up!

Comment: the approach to solve this problem depends on many factors. @RobertP. i've gone for a VBA solution because it does it all in one click but Sid's right you can also solve this using a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check out this.
It assumes a fixed format as it is shown in your example.
It can be made dynamic, but then you need to customize the code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim oCollection         As Collection
Dim oDict               As Variant
Dim oItem               As Object

Dim iCnt                As Integer
Dim iCnt_B              As Integer
Dim iCnt_items          As Integer
Dim iCnt_records        As Integer

Dim iID                 As Integer
Dim iValue              As Integer

Dim strKey              As Variant

'Nr of items
iCnt_items = 3
'Records per item
iCnt_records = 6

'This dictionary will store the items
Set oCollection = New Collection

'Store dictionaries in collection
For iCnt = 0 To iCnt_items - 1
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For iCnt_B = 1 To iCnt_records
            iID = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells((iCnt * (iCnt_records) + (iCnt + 1) + iCnt_B), 1).Value
            Debug.Print iID
            iValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells((iCnt * (iCnt_records) + (iCnt + 1) + iCnt_B), 2).Value
            Debug.Print iValue
            oDict.Add iID, iValue
        Next iCnt_B
        oCollection.Add oDict, "item " & iCnt
Next iCnt

'Write collection to sheet
iCnt = 0
For Each oItem In oCollection
    iCnt = iCnt + 1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1 + iCnt).Value = "item " & iCnt

    iCnt_B = 0
    For Each strKey In oItem.keys
        iCnt_B = iCnt_B + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1 + iCnt_B, 1).Value = strKey
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1 + iCnt_B, 1 + iCnt).Value = oItem(strKey)

    Next
Next oItem

End Sub
```

Edit: sorry for interrupting the conversation -> I didn't follow up the comment section while programming.

Sidenote:

If the ranges you work with are dynamic, I would go with a dictionary.
The reason why I'm saying this is because the dictionary object uses indexing on its records.
The key - pair structure being: ID, value
allows you to directly access the values corresponding the given ID.
In your example you are working with a clear ID - value structure.
Using numeric id's would actually be the fastest.

Comment: Thanks! Since you were first, yours was also the first I tested, and after some refinements it worked perfectly (such as getting the "real" headings etc.) =)

Comment: Cool, I'm happy that it worked out for you. For info: To make the code dynamic, you need to adapt the counter with do ... until loops, but adding items to the dictionary should not be a problem. The writing part would be different, I suggest that you would start with writing the ID's (storing perhaps them in an Array), and then getting the value from the dictionary based on the given ID.

Comment: @KimGysen: Thanks again =) A lot of copy-pasting has been avoided thanks to this answer =)

Answer (score 2):

Since I already worked on this... Here is another way..

**Assumptions:**

1. Data starts at row 5 in Sheet1
2. Output will be generated in Sheet2

**Code:**

The below code uses `Collections` and `Formulas` to achieve what you want.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim ColItems As New Collection, ColSubItems As New Collection
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, N As Long
    Dim itm

    Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With wsInput

        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Columns(1).Insert
        .Range("A5:A" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(""Item"",B5,1)),A4,B5)"

        For i = 5 To lRow
            On Error Resume Next
            If InStr(1, .Range("B" & i).Value, "item", vbTextCompare) Then
                ColItems.Add .Range("B" & i).Value, CStr(.Range("B" & i).Value)
            Else
                ColSubItems.Add .Range("B" & i).Value, CStr(.Range("B" & i).Value)
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i
    End With

    With wsOutput
        .Cells.ClearContents
        N = 2

        '~~> Create Header in Row 1
        For Each itm In ColItems
            .Cells(1, N).Value = itm
            N = N + 1
        Next

        N = 2

        '~~> Create headers in Col 1
        For Each itm In ColSubItems
            .Cells(N, 1).Value = itm
            N = N + 1
        Next

        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        j = 2

        For i = 2 To lcol
            .Range(.Cells(j, i), .Cells(lRow, i)).Formula = "=SUMIFS(" & _
                                                            wsInput.Name & _
                                                            "!C:C," & wsInput.Name & _
                                                            "!A:A," & .Name & _
                                                            "!$" & _
                                                            Split(.Cells(, i).Address, "$")(1) & _
                                                            "$1," & _
                                                            wsInput.Name & _
                                                            "!B:B," & _
                                                            .Name & _
                                                            "!A:A)"
        Next i

        .Rows("1:" & lRow).Value = .Rows("1:" & lRow).Value
    End With

    wsInput.Columns(1).Delete
End Sub
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have tried.

Sheet 1 contains the data. The result is generated in Sheet 2

Sub createTable()

```
Dim counter As Integer
Dim countRow As Integer
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim cellAddress As String
flag = True
countRow = 2
counter = 2

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

For Each cell In Range("a:a")
If counter = 2 Then
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, "Item") Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, counter).Value = cell.Value
        firstItem = cell.Value
        counter = counter + 1

     End If
Else
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
          If InStr(1, cell.Value, "Item") Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, counter).Value = cell.Value
        counter = counter + 1
        flag = False
         End If
         If flag = True Then
         Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column) = cell.Value
         End If

End If
If cell.Value = vbNullString Then
Exit For
End If
Next cell

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Dim counteradd As Integer
counteradd = 2
For Each cell In Range("a:a")
    v = cell.Value
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, "Item") Then
        If cell.Offset(1, 1).Select <> vbNullString Then
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Cells(2, counteradd).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            counteradd = counteradd + 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
        End If
    End If
Next cell
```

End Sub